# nativescript - problem with firebase plugin

Tags: android, gradle, nativescript

I create a fresh nativescript project according to [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/code-a-real-time-app-with-nativescript-push-notifications--cms-29475) article by running these commands:

`tns create fitApp --appid "..."`

`cd fitApp`

`tns plugin add nativescript-plugin-firebase`

`tns run android`

and changed AndroidManifest.xml accordingly and put google-services.json as it said.but i get this error:

> Could not find support-compat.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-compat/28.0.0/support-compat-28.0.0.jar

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "...",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.2.1"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.2.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~7.2.1",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^8.1.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~5.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.5.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~7.2.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.8.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.20.0"
  },
  "gitHead": "f548ec926e75201ab1b7c4a3a7ceefe7a4db15af",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Did you install the android support libraries from Android Studio -> Tools -> SDK Manager?

Comment: Yes.in the Extras,Android Support repositories(rev 47) marked as installed